# Are you going to update reference to Newtonsoft.Json.Net35.dll?

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

I was using Google API Samples for DFA Reporting and found that the client API DLL's use Newtonsoft.Json.Net35.dll. Are you guys planning to update the reference?

I worked around this by removing references to the old DLL and then recompiling the Google.Apis source. But would prefer more if the binaries come with the right version from the Google repository.
Thanks.

Comment: @numbers1311407: that was so insightful. Thanks.

Comment: No problem.  If it helps, I repeated your question out loud in the office and a few other guys replied that no, they weren't going to either.  Steve said he wanted to, but I wouldn't really trust anything that guy says, anyway.

Comment: But some are complaining about the loud absurd sound that's coming out of your side of the work place. Keep it down please!

Just scroll a bit, if you don't see this page in a single screen, and it may help you get some perspective on what I was saying. Google says this is the place for support on client libraries. So unnecessarily jumping in and trying to be snarky doesn't help - anybody.

Comment: Good advice.  I suspect they already think I have Tourette's :-P

Comment: You are fast. I added some more to my comment, just to give perspective to people who may stumble on this stupid thread. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the next release we are going to update this reference. We are planning also to upgrade the library to support PCL 4.0.
Thanks

Comment: We just released 1.4.0-beta several days ago, follow our blog - http://google-api-dotnet-client.blogspot.com/ for more details